# How to change global variables using globals() in python method?

Tags: python, dictionary, global-variables, ipython

If I have the following Python script foo.py :

```
def foo() :
  my_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
  globals().update(my_dict)
  print(A)
  print(B)
  print(C)

foo()
```

I can type this in ipython :

```
run foo.py
=> 1
=> 2
=> 3
A
=> 1
```

However, If I remove the foo() at the bottom :

```
def foo() :
  my_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
  globals().update(my_dict)
  print(A)
  print(B)
  print(C)

# no foo
```

And I type this in ipython :

```
run foo.py
foo()
=> 1
=> 2
=> 3
A
=> NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I get this error. Why is this the case?

Comment: could you give an example of `element_dict`

Comment: @PratikKumar {'H': 1.0, 'He': 4.0, 'C': 12.0}

Comment: @PratikKumar I will change the question to be easier to understand

Comment: @PratikKumar Updated!

Comment: `print('A')` would literally print an A, not 1. When asking questions, please post code you have actually run and the actual output you got by running it.

Comment: @user2357112 Sry about that. I have actually run the code. I was writing this post while running and debugging the thing, so I made a mistake when editing my code in my editor and not editing it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython's [`%run`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) defaults to running the file in a new namespace and then copying the results into your namespace.

When `foo.py` contains a `foo()` call, that creates `A`, `B`, and `C` variables in the new namespace that IPython then copies to your namespace.

When `foo.py` doesn't contain a `foo()` call, you can call `foo()` yourself, but `foo` is still using its original namespace for globals. Calling `foo()` creates `A`, `B`, and `C` variables in `foo`'s original namespace, too late for IPython to pick them up and copy them into your namespace.

You can use `%run` with the `-i` flag to run the file in your namespace directly, avoiding these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `element_dict` a global variable before assigning it.  Once you have an assign statement *anywhere* within a function, the variable being assigned is declared on a local scope only, unless otherwise specified.  In your case, `element_dict` is declared locally due to `element_dict = read_mass_from_file()`.

[See the documentation for more details.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

To actually reference the global variable:

```
def mass_mode() :
  '''
  Add element names and masses to the global variables.
  '''
  global element_dict
  element_dict = read_mass_from_file()
```

will update the `element_dict` from the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have just edited the question. How do you think about the new question? Is the answer still the similar?